# Disable submit button after first submission

Tags: wffm, javascript

I want to stop duplicate WFFM form submissions. I am writing a method to disable the button after first submission.

```
$("form").each(function() {
    var wffm = $(this).attr("data-wffm");
    if (wffm) {
        console.log($(this));
        var submitButton = $("input[type=submit]", $(this));
        submitButton.click(function(e) {
            var checkFormValidity = $(this).parents('form').valid();
            if (checkFormValidity) {
                submitButton.prop('disabled', true);
            }
    }
});
```

The above code disables the button after first submission but it is also not allowing the page to redirect to the Thankyou page.

Am I missing anything?

How to disable the button after first click and also allow the page to redirect to the Thankyou page.

This is not a duplicate question. I don’t want to solve this issue inside wffm.js script. I have written a new script to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable submit button on MVC form that has slow action](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/disable-submit-button-on-mvc-form-that-has-slow-action)

Comment: Not really. I have checked this post but it is doing directly into wffm.js which I want to avoid. Also, if i make changes directly into wffm.js then how will i create a wffm min file?